# Start/stop d3.force dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, diagram

Say I have simple D3.js force diagram like in this example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5141278) . I know all of the magic of force is happening, mainly, in this function here:

```
function tick() {
  path.attr("d", function(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return "M" + 
        d.source.x + "," + 
        d.source.y + "A" + 
        dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + 
        d.target.x + "," + 
        d.target.y;
  });

  node
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; 
    });
}
```

I was wondering, would it be possible to dynamically stop/start the force ? So I could move the nodes around and then for some reason I would enable the force back on and then disable it and move stuff around (im aware the enabling the force would scramble my diagram that ive created while it was disabled).

Could someone give me advice ? I can see how to create a static diagram but it doesn't click for my noob head how to derive my functionality from it... a fiddle is always a clearest example/ suggestion/ answer.

Comment: Use `.start()` and `.stop()`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Ill put together an example to show, that once stop is called when I move a node - force just starts. Maybe You could point where my problem is in there. Thanks

Comment: Lars, here ( [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/351/) )  im using start and stop. Once I click to disable the force and move around the nodes the force starts again. Im sure it has something to do with drag function, but please advise and of-course edit the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/351/).

Comment: Using the force layout drag behaviour triggers a restart on mousemove. You need to use the normal drag behaviour or suppress the restarting.

Comment: Could You please elaborate more on 'normal drag behavior' ?

Comment: [`d3.behavior.drag`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior)

Comment: Ill read it through and see if makes any sense...as much as I appreciate your help, sometimes Your bluntness is more daunting than the questions itself...

Comment: :) My point is that the force layout version of the drag behaviour restarts the force, so you need to use something else.

Comment: are you aware of an example that is using a different 'force layout version of the drag behavior' ? So I could compare the two...

Comment: No. All you have to do is use the normal drag behaviour (there are plenty of examples for that) on the nodes.

Comment: okay, thanks..just trying to understand what is that 'normal drag behavior'...

Comment: The one you get with `d3.behavior.drag()`.

Comment: Ive looked at 23 examples of a tree force diagram, all of them use node.call(force.drag); So if You aware of one please tell me or if you could edit the fidlde with your suggestion it would be event better...If there is a need I can list all examples I looked at...

Comment: I don't think there is an example for that because usually the behaviour where the force layout is restarted after drag is fine. What I'm saying is that you need to use something *different from the usual* because you need behaviour that's *different from the usual*.

Comment: nice, so Your answer to the question is - solve your problem with different code.. Thanks

Comment: found a solution [here](http://bl.ocks.org/norrs/2883411)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer here: http://bl.ocks.org/norrs/2883411

```
var node_drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart)
    .on("drag", dragmove)
    .on("dragend", dragend);

function dragstart(d, i) {
    force.stop() // stops the force auto positioning before you start dragging
}

function dragmove(d, i) {
    d.px += d3.event.dx;
    d.py += d3.event.dy;
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy; 
    tick(); // this is the key to make it work together with updating both px,py,x,y on d !
}

function dragend(d, i) {
    d.fixed = true; // of course set the node to fixed so the force doesn't include the node in its auto positioning stuff
    tick();
    force.resume();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start/stop d3 force from nodes by setting `fixed` property of nodes to false/true. Here is the sample code and [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1k7oc7ym/)

```
d3.select(".toggleButton").on("click",function(){
    var val =  d3.select(this).attr("value");
    if(val=="Disable Force"){
        d3.select(this).attr("value","Enable Force");
        circle.each(function(d){ d.fixed= true; })                    
    }else{
        d3.select(this).attr("value","Disable Force");
        circle.each(function(d){ d.fixed= false; })           
    }
});
```

Comment: Isn't tick function still fired at this point (when nodes are set to fixed ) ? I'm assuming that when force is disabled the tick function is not needed